# Does -tef in the extension stand for anything in documents saved to iCloud in ML?

Tags: macos, iwork, icloud

When you save a new iWork document under Mountain Lion you are given the default extension of .pages-tef or .numbers-tef. These files appear to be directories and a different format than your standard .pages or .numbers file (I haven't had the chance to create a new Keynote preso yet).

Does 'tef' stand for anything? Are these just 'iCloud compatible' files and they've been dubbed '-tef' as the extension? Apple isn't one to name things without a specific intent and nothing specific comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the iCloud version of the iWork file format. A good article about it (albeit still without explanation of the acronym) can be found [on Mac Observer](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/digging_deep_into_iwork_document_sharing_in_mountain_lion/).

Comment: Definitely a good article and thoroughly explains the different types and specifically both the Mac iCloud and iOS iCloud -tef files which I didn't know about. This article does indeed answer 95% of what I was curious about. Now just to find out what it '-tef' stands for...